# mysql group by error,cannot see it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query,and I am having the following error returned however I cannot find the problem,

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_' at line 14

this is my query,

```
SELECT `candidates`.`candidate_id`, 
       `candidates`.`first_name`, 
       `candidates`.`surname`, 
       `candidates`.`DOB`, 
       `candidates`.`gender`, 
       `candidates`.`talent`, 
       `candidates`.`location`, 
       `candidates`.`availability`, 
       DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '00-%m-%d')) 
                   as `age`, 
       `candidate_assets`.`url`, 
       `candidate_assets`.`asset_size` 
FROM `candidates` 
LEFT JOIN `candidate_assets` ON `candidate_assets`.`candidates_candidate_id` = `candidates`.`candidate_id` 
WHERE `candidates`.`availability` = 'yes' 
AND candidates.talent = "presenter" 
AND candidates.gender = "male" 
HAVING DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '00-%m-%d')) <= 39
AND HAVING DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(`candidates`.`DOB`, '00-%m-%d')) <=29 
GROUP BY `candidates`.`candidate_id`
```

what is the problem, I am not an avid user of mySQL

Comment: **PLEASE** don't post a query on a single line like that.  Whitespace is  your friend.

Comment: @sico87 It seems as though you're calculating the age based on the year only. You know, I was born in May, my age changes in May, not just with the year. Consider using `DateDiff`.

Comment: @MPelletier, you may need to scroll to the right - the age calculation includes a Boolean expression checking whether the current date is earlier in the year than the `DOB`. `DateDiff` can only return values in days, not years.

Comment: @MarkBannister Still, you can turn days into years, divide by 365.25 or something. There must be a better way to calculate someone's age. Worst case, a stored procedure.

Comment: Dividing by 365.25 would need to include conditional checks for whether the current year is a leap year, since where true there will be n+1 leap days in 4n years under such circumstances, while there would only be n leap days in 4n years where not a leap year. Not to mention the century rule for leap years... Basically, it would be much better if MySQL included an interval argument in `DateDiff`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things I see right away:

1 - `HAVING` should only occur once in the query, not twice.
2 - `HAVING` should always come after `GROUP BY`
3 - `HAVING` only applies to **AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS**, not something like a date comparison.  If you want a date comparison you should use a `WHERE` clause.

There may be more but your query is extremely hard to read in the current "format".  If you need more help, please put at least **SOME** effort into making your question readable.

Comment: I thought you could use HAVING when comparing a field that had been created in the query, i.e age

Comment: @sico87 - `HAVING` is used for aggregate functions in standard SQL.  Later versions of MySQL allow use of aliased fields from the query.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use the `HAVING` keyword once. Take the second one away after the `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out your less thans `<` both before `from` on your `age` column and in `having`. You have more than should be. Invalid syntax.